# Help me find a story from my childhood: Deep Space Cryosleep (End of the World)

Tags: aliens, story-identification

The world is ending due to an asteroid plummeting towards earth. The protagonist's mother, himself and a handful of important people escape earth in a spaceship and left in cryosleep, which was considered quack technology. Eventually they're picked up by a group of aliens and revived. Before the protagonist left, he saw a girl he had a crush on die on live television presumably by some of the asteroids.

Comment: Do you possibly remember any other details? Such as when you read it, etc. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details. It would really help us to help you.

Comment: Never mind found it, it's called Remnants by KA Applegate.